# Failed to pass value between middlewares

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I got this in app.js

```
var routes = require('./routes/index');

app.use(function(req,res,next) {

    res.something = 'something_value';
    next();
  }

});

app.use('/', routes);
```

Then I have a routes folder, it has index.js I do

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {


    console.log(req.something)


});
```

but I got undefined. What's wrong?

I also tried `req.body.something`, I got undefined too.

Comment: Because you set `res.something` not `req.something`

Comment: `res.something` is defined, not `req`